# How to get the index of the table into columns array in antd table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I am using antd table for displaying dynamic multiple tables in a react app by mapping a array and rendering the table inside of a collapse of antd
Code: -

```
import { Button, Input, Table, Collapse } from "antd";
import React, { useState } from "react";

export default function LogbookForm() {
  const { Panel } = Collapse;
  const [data, setdata] = useState([
    {
      section_name: "XYZ",
      details: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "c++",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "python",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 3,
          name: "native",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 4,
          name: "react",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 5,
          name: "java",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 6,
          name: "javs script",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      section_name: "ABC",
      details: [
        {
          id: 1,
          name: "c++",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
        {
          id: 2,
          name: "python",
          goals: 6,
          assists: 10,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);
  console.log(data);
  const [tableData, setTableData] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "c++",
      goals: 6,
      assists: 10,
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "python",
      goals: 6,
      assists: 10,
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "native",
      goals: 6,
      assists: 10,
    },
    {
      id: 4,
      name: "react",
      goals: 6,
      assists: 10,
    },
    {
      id: 5,
      name: "java",
      goals: 6,
      assists: 10,
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      name: "javs script",
      goals: 6,
      assists: 10,
    },
  ]);
  const onInputChange = (key, index, record, text, i) => (e) => {
    console.log(key, index, record, text, i, e);
    const newData = [...tableData];
    newData[index][key] = e.target.value;
    setTableData(newData);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "process Stage",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      i: "",
      render: (text, record, index, i) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index, text, record, i)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "goals",
      title: "standard",
      key: "goals",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("goals", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "assists",
      title: "actual",
      key: "assists",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("assists", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "strength",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "real",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "volume",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "ph",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "Temp",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "Start Time",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      dataIndex: "name",
      title: "End Time",
      width: "7%",
      key: "name",
      render: (text, record, index) => (
        <Input
          key={index}
          value={text}
          onChange={onInputChange("name", index)}
        />
      ),
    },
    {
      render: (text, record, index) => {
        return (
          <Button
            type="text"
            className="dlt-action"
            key={index}
            onClick={() => handleDelete(index)}
          >
            <i className="far fa-trash-alt"></i>
          </Button>
        );
      },
    },
  ];
  const handleDelete = (index) => {
    let temp = [...tableData];
    temp.splice(index, 1);
    setTableData([...temp]);
  };
  const handlesubmit = () => {
    console.log(tableData);
  };
  const handleAddRows = () => {
    console.log(columns.length);
    const obj = {
      id: tableData.length + 1,
      name: "",
      goals: null,
      assists: null,
    };
    let temp = [...tableData];
    temp.push(obj);
    setTableData([...temp]);
  };
  const addDetails = (i) => {
    let temp = [...data];
    const obj = {
      id: temp[i].details.length + 1,
      name: "",
      goals: null,
      assists: null,
    };
    temp[i].details.push(obj);
    setdata([...temp]);
    console.log(data);
    // console.log(obj);
  };
  const callback = (k) => {
    console.log(k);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <Collapse expandIconPosition="right" onChange={callback}>
        {data &&
          data.length > 0 &&
          data.map((section, index) => {
            return (
              <Panel key={index} header={section.section_name}>
                <Table
                  key={(record) => record.id}
                  columns={columns}
                  dataSource={section.details}
                />
              </Panel>
            );
          })}
      </Collapse>
      <Button onClick={() => handlesubmit()}>save changes</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

To perform crud operations inside each table, i would require the variable 'index' so that i can operate the array as required, i am not able to retrieve the information that which table the user is currently working on, and thus cannot determine the way to perform operations required like edit create and delete.
I want to know is there any way to pass the variable 'index' to the columns so that,i can perform operations??

Illustration: -
[demo photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWwIN.png)

Comment: second parameter of map function is index of the current item and "in" is a keyword, I don't think , your can use it

Comment: its just for differentiating, i have used index as the second parameter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you go the documents of ANTD you always find a section named API in bottom of every component which provide you acceptable props and also events. As for the tables there you can find that you can configure an onClick on each row which will provide you useful stuff such as index: https://ant.design/components/table/#API .

Just like their document:

```
<Table onRow={(record, rowIndex) => {
return {
  onClick: event => {}, // click row
  onDoubleClick: event => {}, // double click row
  onContextMenu: event => {}, // right button click row
  onMouseEnter: event => {}, // mouse enter row
  onMouseLeave: event => {}, // mouse leave row
}}}/>
```

Call a function on these events and pass their data such as rowIndex or event itself to your function and log them in your console and it will give you the details you want.

Comment: Thankyou, but it gives the index of the table rows itself, what i need is the main array index(here index) in the onChange event of input fields in the columns array

Comment: @SiddharajsinhGohil Did you tried also event and record? They should provide you details you want

Comment: Yes, i tried the index,text,and record and also the event handling, but not getting the required index, infact, i was getting the index of the rows inside the table

Answer (score 0):

Thankyou for all your suggestions, i found a way to solve the issue, by handling callback on mouse enter into the table, i am capturing the parent index as it is available in the same